# Recover password from spreadsheet

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013

I set a password on an Excel 2013 spreadsheet but now I don't remember it.

Is there any way that I can remove or recover it? It is an .xlsx document

Comment: Probably not in a easier way

Comment: Even if the way isn't easy, is it possible?